# Hiding fields listed twice from debugger window

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-debugging

When inspecting the Response of a Webservice in the debugger window, every field of the response is listed twice - once with an appendix of *Field*.

[image]
<sub>(source: [mlkshk.com](https://mlkshk.com/r/KK77))</sub>

How can I hide the second listing?

The webservice reference is added as outlined [on the msdn library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/bb628649%28v=vs.140%29), so I don't want to add the [attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/754393/hiding-fields-from-the-debugger) *[DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]* manually.

Comment: Have you considered writing a visualizer?
Just an idea...  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164759.aspx

Comment: There is no way to hide it other than writing your own visualizer or using the `[DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]` attribute.  

You can insert it on your code programmatically using `Reflection.Emit` namespace though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit of a hack, and isn't as presentable as the regular Watch window would be, but you could use this process.

1. Add a GetFieldValues utility method that would extract just the field values you want.
2. While debugging, open the [Immediate Window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f177hahy%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)
3. In the Immediate Window, create a variable that captures the results of GetFieldValues
4. In the Watch window, add that newly created variable.

That way you can filter out the stuff you don't want to see. Here's a screenshot of it in action:
[image: Visual Studio immediate and watch windows]

Utility method:

```
public static List<Tuple<String,Object>> GetFieldValues(Object instance)
{
    var fields = instance.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);
    var fieldValues = new List<Tuple<String, Object>>();
    foreach (var f in fields) { fieldValues.Add(new Tuple<string, Object>(f.Name, f.GetValue(instance))); }
    return fieldValues;
}
```

And the Immediate Window code:

```
var blah = J.GetFieldValues(this);
```